# Django ModelForm won't allow Null value for required field?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have a Model with this field...

```
fulfillment_flag = models.CharField(pgettext_lazy('Delivery group field', 'Fulfillment Flag'), max_length=255,
                                        null=True, choices=FULFILLMENT_FLAG_CHOICES)
```

And here is my form...

```
class FulfillmentFlagForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = DeliveryGroup
        fields = ['fulfillment_flag', ]

    def clean_fulfillment_flag(self):
        return self.cleaned_data['fulfillment_flag'] or None
```

I have an HTML select drop down that has a blank value option at the top.  Every time I select the blank option and click Save, form will not save it as a Null value on my model.  It'll save any of the other fields though, just not the blank one.  And it will tell me that the field is required as well.

How can I tell the form to just save the blank value as Null?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#null

> Avoid using null on string-based fields such as CharField and TextField because empty string values will always be stored as empty strings, not as NULL. If a string-based field has null=True, that means it has two possible values for “no data”: NULL, and the empty string. In most cases, it’s redundant to have two possible values for “no data;” the Django convention is to use the empty string, not NULL.
>
> For both string-based and non-string-based fields, you will also need to set blank=True if you wish to permit empty values in forms, as the null parameter only affects database storage (see blank).

Do `blank=True` instead and save `""` instead of `None`.

Comment: `blank=True` is the only strictly required part - that's what controls whether the field is required or not. But the recommendation about not using `null` for `CharField` is worth following.

Comment: What form field would be recommended to use in my situation then?

Comment: All fields accept empty/no input if you tell them so. You can either tell them by specifying `required=False` in the Form, or by saying `blank=True` in the model. Doing latter will let you use a `ModelForm` and prevents repetetive code.

Comment: Ok thanks for that clarification.  My confusion was with `blank=True`.  I understood that to mean that my field would store blank values in the DB along with Null values.  But `blank=True` refers to validation.  All is well now, thank you.